Trouble Getting Share Services in NinjaTrader
I'm encountering an issue in NinjaTrader where I'm trying to get the names of all configured share services, particularly for Telegram, but I'm getting an error saying that Globals does not contain the definition ShareServices.
Here is the relevant code:
else if (State == State.Configure)
{
    // Get the names of all Telegram share services
    telegramServiceNames = Globals.ShareServices
        .Where(s => s.Name.ToLower().Contains("telegram"))
        .Select(s => s.Name)
        .ToList();
    if (telegramServiceNames.Count > 0 && string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedServiceName))
    {
        SelectedServiceName = telegramServiceNames[0];
    }

    // Get the names of all accounts
    accountNames = Account.All.Select(a => a.Name).ToList();
    if (accountNames.Count > 0 && string.IsNullOrEmpty(SelectedAccountName))
    {
        SelectedAccountName = accountNames[0];
    }
}

else if (State == State.DataLoaded)
{
    // Find the selected share service
    selectedTelegramService = Globals.ShareServices.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Name == SelectedServiceName);

    // Find the selected account
    selectedAccount = Account.All.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Name == SelectedAccountName);
    if (selectedAccount != null)
    {
        selectedAccount.ExecutionUpdate += OnExecutionUpdate;
    }
}

When attempting to get the names of all share services configured by the user, I receive an error stating that Globals does not contain the definition ShareServices. How can I retrieve all the share service names in my indicator for NinjaTrader 8?

Where the code specified Globals.ShareServices replace it with Globals.GeneralOptions.ShareServices
And have a look at this page from the Nt forum
